# QT program crashes after connect()

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, singleton, signals-slots

I'm trying to write my new app, but it crashes every time I press a button on QDialog.

Here's my code :

mainwindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "creatlist.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;

}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QDialog* creatList;

public slots:
    void tableFull(){
      ...some code here...
     }

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

creatlist.h :

```
#include <QDialog>
#include "mainwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class creatlist;
}

class MainWindow;

class creatlist : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit creatlist(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~creatlist();
    MainWindow* mainwindow;
signals:
    void updateList();

public slots:
    void ready(){
       ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////crash
     connect(this,SIGNAL(updateList()),mainwindow,SLOT(tableFull()));
     emit updateList();

   }

private:
    Ui::creatlist *ui;
};
```

If i try to send some signals my app crashes with a Segmentation Fault.

I did:

```
void creatlist::ready()
{
mainwindow = new MainWindow(this);
emit mainwindow->linktableFull();
}
```

but if I try to do `QTextBroser.append("hue hue");` in linktableFull(), QTextBrowser is always empty.

Comment: Obviously, `mainwindow` doesn't point to any instance of `MainWindow`.

Comment: Learn to use your debugger, you would have found the source of the problem immediately.

Comment: you could have improved your question by posting the crash information (launching your program from a terminal or a debugger would give more information)

Answer (score 0):

Your `QTextBrowser` always empty because you create new `mainwindow` object in every `ready()` function. You should create mainwindow object once and use same `mainwindow` object throughout code. You can create new `mainwindow` object in `creatlist` constructor.